# What is the O.S. variant it uses in a Dockerfile if the 1st line is: FROM haproxy:2.3?

Tags: dockerfile

What is the O.S. variant it uses in a Dockerfile if the 1st line is: FROM haproxy:2.3?

When you build it using docker command, what is the default O. S. does it uses?

Comment: It's using debian. To be specific debian:buster-slim. Checkout the official image repo: https://github.com/docker-library/haproxy

Answer (score 0):

It uses Debian.
If you head over to the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/haproxy/blob/6cb254be8673430d79a04f1e27b3b722a5b2cadd/2.3/Dockerfile) of haproxy:2.3, you can see it from the first line:

```
FROM debian:buster-slim
```